# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python on visual code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm having problems with installing python3.10 on visual code!

[image: screenshot]

need help ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to extensions on the left side of VScode, and downloading python from there.

If you don't see an extensions section, go to the bottom left and click settings -> extensions. Then search for python and install.

Answer (score 0):

##### You have installed python3.10 in the Microsoft store, and the python interpreter version of your current workspace is displayed in the lower right corner of vscode.

[image]

As for your `pip` command, you should open the path containing the *requirement.txt* file in a terminal, or indicate the path to the *requirement.txt* in the command. This way you won't get a file not found error.

You should open your project folder with vscode and start writing python code. Again before that you also need to install the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension. It is recommended that you start with the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial), it will be easier to get started.